# Problem in Passing Kendo DropDownList Filter Value as Object Type Property in a Complex Type

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Kendo jquery DropdownList with Server Filtering.

```
var personnelId = $('#PersonnelId').val();
$("#drpPersonnel").kendoDropDownList({
                        optionLabel: "Select...",
                        filter: "contains",
                        dataTextField: "FullName",
                        dataValueField: "Id",
                        change: function (e) {
                            $('#PersonnelId').val(this.value());
                        },
                        autoBind: true,
                        dataSource: {
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    headers: {
                                        "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
                                    },
                                    type: "Post",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    url: "/Base/User/GetAllPersonnel"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).data("kendoDropDownList").value(personnelId);
```

I am using the following DataSourceRequest Model to binding filters, paging, sorting, and other options from Kendo-UI Components.

```
public class DataSourceRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies how many items to take.
    /// </summary>
    public int Take { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies how many items to skip.
    /// </summary>
    public int Skip { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the requested sort order.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Sort> Sort { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the requested filter.
    /// </summary>
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }

}
```

Filter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a filter expression of Kendo DataSource.
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class Filter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the sorted field (property). Set to <c>null</c> if the <c>Filters</c> property is set.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the filtering operator. Set to <c>null</c> if the <c>Filters</c> property is set.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the filtering value. Set to <c>null</c> if the <c>Filters</c> property is set.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the filtering logic. Can be set to "or" or "and". Set to <c>null</c> unless <c>Filters</c> is set.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "logic")]
    public string Logic { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the child filter expressions. Set to <c>null</c> if there are no child expressions.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "filters")]
    public IEnumerable<Filter> Filters { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mapping of Kendo DataSource filtering operators to Dynamic Linq
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> operators = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"eq", "="},
        {"neq", "!="},
        {"lt", "<"},
        {"lte", "<="},
        {"gt", ">"},
        {"gte", ">="},
        {"startswith", "StartsWith"},
        {"endswith", "EndsWith"},
        {"contains", "Contains"},
        {"doesnotcontain", "Contains"}
    };
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a flattened list of all child filter expressions.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<Filter> All()
    {
        var filters = new List<Filter>();
        Collect(filters);
        return filters;
    }
    private void Collect(IList<Filter> filters)
    {
        if (Filters != null && Filters.Any())
        {
            foreach (Filter filter in Filters)
            {
                filters.Add(filter);
                filter.Collect(filters);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!filters.Select(s => s.Value).Equals(this.Value) && !filters.Select(s => s.Field).Equals(this.Field))
            {
                if (filters.Any(x => x.Field != this.Field && x.Value != this.Value))
                {
                    filters.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the filter expression to a predicate suitable for Dynamic Linq e.g. "Field1 = @1 and Field2.Contains(@2)"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filters">A list of flattened filters.</param>
    public string ToExpression(IList<Filter> filters)
    {
        if (Filters != null && Filters.Any())
        {
            return "(" + String.Join(" " + Logic + " ", Filters.Select(filter => filter.ToExpression(filters)).ToArray()) + ")";
        }
        int index = filters.IndexOf(this);
        string comparison = operators[Operator.ToLower()];

        if (Operator == "doesnotcontain")
        {
            return String.Format("!{0}.{1}(@{2})", Field, comparison, index);
        }
        if (comparison == "StartsWith" || comparison == "EndsWith" || comparison == "Contains")
        {
            return String.Format("{0}.{1}(@{2})", Field, comparison, index);
        }
        return String.Format("{0} {1} @{2}", Field, comparison, index);
    }
}
```

Each filter in `IEnumerable<Filter> Filters` can have a value with a different type such as `string`, `string[]` and `int`. For this reason, *Value* property is an **object** type. It's working fine with Kendo-Grid but with Kendo Dropdownlist this value is null.

[image]

[image]

It should be noted that if I change the *Value* property type to **string**, it's work.

This is how I'm using `DataSourceRequest` and `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`. The `Value` as `object` convert to other types depend on *field* that comes in where clause in the query.

```
public async Task<DataSourceResult> GetAllPersonnel(DataSourceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        try
        {

            IQueryable<Personnel> query = _dbSetPersonnel.AsNoTracking();

            if (request.Filter != null && request.Filter.Logic != null)
            {

                var filters = request.Filter.All().Where(c => c.Value != null).ToList();
                if (filters.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var filter in filters)
                    {
                        Type valueType = filter.Value.GetType();
                        if (valueType.IsArray)
                        {
                            filter.Value = ((string[])(filter.Value)).First();
                        }

                        if (filter.Field == "ContactNo")
                        {
                            bool hasContactFilter = int.TryParse(filter.Value.ToString(), out int contactNo);
                            filter.Value = contactNo;
                        }
                    }

                    var values = filters.Select(f => f.Value).ToArray();

                    request.Filter.Filters = request.Filter.Filters.Where(x => x.Value != null);
                    string predicate = (request.Filter).ToExpression(filters);
                    predicate = predicate.Replace("StateName", "City.State.Name");
                    predicate = predicate.Replace("CityName", "City.Name");

                    query = query.Where(predicate, values);
                }
            }

            var total = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (request.Sort != null && request.Sort.Any())
            {
                var ordering = string.Join(",", request.Sort.Select(s => s.ToExpression()));
                ordering = ordering.Replace("StateName", "City.State.Name");
                ordering = ordering.Replace("CityName", "City.Name");

                query = query.OrderBy(ordering);
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(c => c.LastName);
            }
          
            query = query.Skip(request.Skip).Take(request.Take);

            var list = await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            List<PersonnelViewModel> viewModel = new List<PersonnelViewModel>();

            _mapper.Map<List<Personnel>, List<PersonnelViewModel>>(list, viewModel);
            return new DataSourceResult
            {
                Data = viewModel,
                Total = total
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I need to know how can bind object type to **action** in .net core, If anyone suggests another approach to solve the problem, please let me know.

Comment: Then use it as a string. It will make any difference in a query or something?

Comment: I used it in the whole project as object. This problem accurred because I updated kendo-ui and upgraded mcv to mv core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you note, the request parameters pass to the action as `FormData` and it's because `public object Value { get; set; }` is `null`. Therefore, it needs to pass parameters as `JSON` and use `[FromBody]` in action.
There is [transport.parameterMap](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.parametermap) function in `Datasource configuration` which converts the request parameters to a format suitable for the remote service.
I changed the kendo DropDownList configuration and use [kendo.stringify](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/stringify) to serialize parameters and add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` to `tranport`, it's working.

```
$("#drpPersonnel").kendoDropDownList({
                    optionLabel: "Select...",
                    filter: "contains",
                    dataTextField: "FullName",
                    dataValueField: "Id",
                    change: function (e) {
                        $('#PersonnelId').val(this.value());
                    },
                    autoBind: true,
                    dataSource: {
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                headers: {
                                    "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
                                },
                                type: "Post",
                                dataType: "json",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: "/Base/User/GetAllPersonnel"
                            },
                                parameterMap: function (options) {
                                    return kendo.stringify(options);
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }).data("kendoDropDownList").value(personnelId);
```

and `action` in contoller looks like:

```
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<JsonResult> GetAllPersonnel([FromBody] DataSourceRequest request)
            {
                var personnel = await _personnelService.GetAllPersonnel(request, cancellationToken);
                return Json(personnel.Data);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the asp.net core model binding will bind the data according to the formdata's name. But the  DataSourceRequest Model doesn't match it, so you will find some filter doesn't bind complete.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to use below model class:

```
public class DataSourceRequest
{
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public FilterForCore filter { get; set; }
}

public class FilterForCore
{
    public string logic { get; set; }
    public List<FilterEntry> filters { get; set; }
}

public class FilterEntry
{
    [DataMember(Name = "field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```